# Fancybox not loading in IE, ignoring return false

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I'm trying to enable fancybox so that when a user clicks on the thumbnail the video opens in a Fancybox window/overlay. I have the following JavaScript + html, everything is working fine on all browsers except Internet Explorer. In Internet Explorer it just goes to the youtube page containing the video. Anybody familiar with the problem and knows of a solution?

```
$('body').delegate('.video .thumbholder a','click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : $(this).title,
            'width'         : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : $(this).attr('href').replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong (an exception is thrown) before your `return false` statement, the browser will follow the link, and navigate away, before you get to see the error message. This is probably what is happening in IE.

Hard code the `href` property in the fancybox options, and let the `href` of the actual anchor be `javascript:void(0);`. This way, you can see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer m8. I tried something similar before, and tried your solution just to be sure. I doesn't work and IE7 does not return any errors. Thing is when I hard code the href property nor the fancybox opens nor the youtube page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Put this before your $.fancybox call.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This will stop the href from triggering.